# Is using a PendingIntent for receiving location updates a security risk?

Tags: android

In Reto Meiers blog post [A Deep Dive Into Location](http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) on the Android Blog, and in his talk, he recommends using a [`PendingIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) for receiving updates from the [`LocationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html). Since you can't create local-only intent broadcasts(see the [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)) with a PendingIntent then virtually anybody can send these broadcasts to your application, right? Wouldn't this be a security risk?

Comment: I am not shure: Is your question: "Every other app/service can send false location-broadcasts to your local BroadcastReceiver to impose a security risk"?

Comment: Does my answer answer your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a receiver registered in the manifest receive the PendingIntent - enable and disable as needed via `PackageManager` - specify no intent filters - the receiver will be implicitly `android:exported=false`, so no one but your app will be able to wake him up. Also [`setComponent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent%28android.content.ComponentName%29) on the intent you pass into PendingIntent to be handled by your receiver only