# How to secure location updates broadcast receiver

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

Following Google's [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent) on implementing broadcast receiver for fused location update I've noticed that the broadcast receiver is exported which is a security risk.
A snippet:

```
<receiver android:name=".LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationupdatespendingintent.LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES.equals(action)) {
...
```

How would you recommend protecting this broadcast receiver ? Is there a way for me to verify it arrived from Google play services ? This is not inter-application communication as described here [Android make broadcast receiver secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977410/android-make-broadcast-receiver-secure)

There was a possible suggestion here - [Is using a PendingIntent for receiving location updates a security risk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097139/is-using-a-pendingintent-for-receiving-location-updates-a-security-risk) but it's not relevant because I need the receiver to always be open

Comment: if you are  unregister your Receiver  in onDestroy(). Otherwise, there will be memory leak....my suggestion is try to use the service..

Comment: If your app targets O then service won't work

Comment: To be honest I'm really surprised that's this is the example that Android gives, especially after security became a major issue in Android development, maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: I tried with O also service is working...Pending Intent is working in O also..i test bro..

Comment: And your target SDK is O ?

Comment: ...i given target as 25....Might heply full check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315946/how-to-track-users-full-day-location-using-google-map